# Convert BufferedReader To InputStream

Tags: java, android, inputstream, bufferedstream

I just finished writing a bunch of code that works fine when reading from internal resource :))))

```
try {
        SeriesDataXMLPullParserHandler seriesDataXmlPullParserHandler = new SeriesDataXMLPullParserHandler();
        entries = seriesDataXmlPullParserHandler.parse(getAssets().open("series_box.xml"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("errorOpeningSeries", e.getMessage());
    }
    Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Entry>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Entry entryOne, Entry entryTwo) {
            return (entryOne.getSeriesName().compareTo(entryTwo.getSeriesName()));
        }
    });
    listView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.id.details_SeriesName, entries));
```

"SeriesDataXMLPullParserHandler" class parse data from xml file that uses InputStream as argument

here is "SeriesDataXMLPullParserHandler" class

```
public class SeriesDataXMLPullParserHandler {
List<Entry> entries;
private Entry entry;
private String text;

public SeriesDataXMLPullParserHandler() {
    entries = new ArrayList<>();
}

public List<Entry> getEntries() {
    return entries;
}

public List<Entry> parse(InputStream inputStream) {
    XmlPullParserFactory xmlPullParserFactory = null;
    XmlPullParser xmlPullParser = null;
    try {
        xmlPullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        xmlPullParserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        xmlPullParser = xmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser();

        xmlPullParser.setInput(inputStream, null);

        int eventType = xmlPullParser.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagname = xmlPullParser.getName();
            switch (eventType) {
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("series")) {
                        entry = new Entry();
                    }
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = xmlPullParser.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("series")) {
                        entries.add(entry);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
                        entry.setId(text);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("Actors")) {
                        entry.setActors(text);
                    }else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("Genre")) {
                        entry.setGenre(text);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("IMDB_ID")) {
                        entry.setImdb_id(text);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("Language")) {
                        entry.setLanguage(text);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("Network")) {
                        entry.setNetwork(text);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("NetworkID")) {
                        entry.setNetwork_id(text);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("Overview")) {
                        entry.setOverview(text);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("SeriesID")) {
                        entry.setSeriesId(text);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("SeriesName")) {
                        entry.setSeriesName(text);
                    } 
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            eventType = xmlPullParser.next();
        }

    } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return entries;
}
```

}

but the problem is when I want to get data from server, it comes in "InputStreamReader" type

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

the question is how do I change the type of "BufferedReader" to "InputStream" for parsing data??? 
or the best way to do such a thing ???
sorry for bad english :)

Comment: Why not just use `xmlFactory.setInput(Reader)` instead?

Comment: @JonSkeet would you mind be specific about that? and give me an example? :/

Comment: Sorry, I meant `xmlPullParser.setInput(reader)`. Basically there's no reason why your code has to take an `InputStream` - if you just change it to take a `Reader` instead, that'll be fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thank You man :))) just another clue and We'll fine :)) Reader takes BufferedReader or I have to cast that?

Comment: A `BufferedReader` *is* a `Reader` (please read the documentation).

Comment: `problem is when I want to get data from server, it comes in "InputStreamReader" type

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));`. Nonsense. It comes as url.openStream(). And that is an InputStream. Use it directly.